# How to add icon conditional formating based on another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to add an icon to cells based on rule if another cell contains a value.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jknEb.png) are cells which I want to format. On the left side I want to add icon in the right side of the cell if the cell in the column Note of the same row contains a value. For Example, "Formale Systeme" cell should have that icon because there is a note "2" in that row.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlqN6.png) is an example how it should look.

Cells on the left side are D7-D66 and cells on the right side are I7-I66

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer on this site: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/05/excel-conditional-formatting-icon-sets-data-bars-color-scales/